# Where is the run button in a default installation of Visual C++ 2010?

Tags: visual-c++

I have download Visual C++ 2010 and everything is fine but I have a small problem. It does not have the method **start without debugging**. Why? and how can i run project?

Comment: You can customize all menus somewhere deep inside VS settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably using the Express Edition of Visual C++ 2010. Some functions have been hidden by default in these editions. I believe the Microsoft's intention behind this is to not confuse novice users as much.

Either use the keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+F5) or switch Visual C++ 2010 Express into Expert Mode. The Expert Mode setting can be found in the menu "Tools" under "Settings":

[Screenshot of the Expert Settings option in Visual Studio Express http://www.nuclex.org/images/stories/blog/gamedev/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010-expert-settings.png](http://www.nuclex.org/images/stories/blog/gamedev/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010-expert-settings.png)

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's changed it should be to just press `Ctrl-F5` to run it without the debugger.